# Redux wont update store after first run (only this reducer)

Tags: redux

I'm having trouble with the below reducer not updating the store after first run:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case "SET_STARRED":

    let starred = action.bucket.starred;
    let active = action.bucket.active;

    console.log("STA ", starred);
    console.log("ACT ", active);

    return{
      ...state, starred: starred,
      ...state, active: active
    }

  default:
    return state
}
```

My other reducers are working great, this is one of the simpler ones so...
Initial run sets the store fine, then each update the reducer logs what I expect, but the store doesn't change?

Have I done something silly?

I've checked and the data fed in appears identical in formatting each run and runs only once (thought it was getting overwritten).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have `...state` in there twice, so it's very likely the `starred` field update would get overwritten by the old value.

As a side note, you can simplify that code just a bit using ES6 destructuring and object literal syntax (to go along with the Object Spread syntax you're already using):

```
const {starred, action} = action.bucket;

return {
    ...state,
    starred,
    active
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that just made me consider where else I've gone wrong in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Try returning this instead:

```
return Object.assign({}, state,
    {
        starred: starred,
        active: active
    }
)
```

This will return a copy of state, but with the 'starred' and 'active' attributes replaced with the new values.

Comment: Thanks, that's neat.